# Proving uniform convergence of an integral-defined function on compact sets

Tags: compactness, lebesgue-integral, uniform-convergence

> If $f$ is a compactly supported smooth (infinitely differentiable) function into $[0, 1]$ such that $\int f(x)dx = 1$, $g$ is a continuous function, and $f_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{\epsilon}f(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$, show that $g_\epsilon(x) := \int f_\epsilon(x-y)g(y)dy$ converges to g(x) uniformly on compact sets.

I have proven that $g_\epsilon$ is also smooth, with nth derivative $g^{(n)}_\epsilon(x) = \int f^{(n)}_\epsilon(x-y)g(y)dy$, though I'm not sure how helpful that is for this part.

My first guess is to let C be any compact set and try to find some upper bound on $\sup_{x \in C} \lbrace |g(x) - \int \frac{1}{\epsilon} f((x - y)/\epsilon)g(y)dy| \rbrace$ which tends to $0$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, but I'm not really sure how to estimate this supremum since the functions and set involved seem too "general" to say anything that's both specific *and* helpful about them. Am I missing something obvious? Would it be better to pick some particular bunch of compact sets that behave "nicely" for this calculation and somehow extrapolate out to all of them?

Comment: In the statement of your problem, does $f$ have compact support?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot that and a couple of other conditions. It's edited in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have shown $g_{\epsilon}(x)\to g(x)$ pointwise a.e. $x$,  modify the estimate of $|g_{\epsilon}(x)-g(x)|$ used in that proof, noting that $g$ is uniformly continuous on compact sets (hint: you evoked the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (LDT) to prove a.e. convergence; with a uniformly continuous $g$, what can you say about the relevant limit in the LDT?).

**ADDITIONAL HINTS:**

I assume you mean $f$ is compactly supported on $[0,1]$, not a map into $[0,1]$.

For fixed $x\in\mathbb{R}$ note that $f_{\epsilon}$ is compactly supported on $[0,\epsilon]$.

Therefore (using the unit mass property of $f$),

$$|g_{\epsilon}(x)-g(x)|=\left|\int_{x}^{x+\epsilon}f_{\epsilon}(x-y)[g(y)-g(x)]\;dy\right|.$$

If you carry this out a bit further you will get to

$$|g_{\epsilon}(x)-g(x)|\leq\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x)\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int_{x}^{x+\epsilon}|g(y)-g(x)|\;dy.$$

This quantity tends to $0$ by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem as $\epsilon\to0$.  This proves pointwise convergence for even an integrable $g$.

Now if the regularity of $g$ is upgraded to continuity, and we pick a compact interval $I$, then $g$ is uniformly continuous on $I$, and so the limit in the Lebesgue differentiation theorem is uniform in $x$.  This implies that $g_{\epsilon}\to g$ uniformly on $I$.  Now take an arbitrary compact set $K$ and use the previous argument to deduce $g_{\epsilon}\to g$ uniformly on $K$ since $K\subset I$ for some compact interval $I$.

Comment: I haven't done anything with a.e. convergence, which seems unnecessary if my goal is only convergence on compact sets? Either way, I'm not familiar with the LDT as such (I mean, I understand it's an extension of the fundamental theorem of calculus, but not so much its proof), and attempting to understand its relationship to this problem has left me confused, possibly because I tried consulting Wikipedia's article on it.

Comment: Actually, since uniform convergence is usually harder to demonstrate than pointwise convergence, a good starting point would be to prove pointwise convergence first, even if restricted to compact sets.  I elaborated on my answer a bit; hopefully it will get you started.

Comment: I don't know if it changes much, but f actually is specifically stated to be from R to [0, 1] and compactly supported, without any comment on what compact set its support is. This problem is related to applications in probability is likely why.

Comment: Ah, then you will have to adjust the limits in the integral accordingly to take into account the domain.  But note for instance that if $f$ is supported on $K\subset\mathbb{R}$, then $f_{\epsilon}$ is supported on a subset $K_{\epsilon}\subset K$.  The specific range of $f$ is irrelevant, only that it allows for $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f=1$ and that $f\geq0$.